# timm: AttributeError: 'DataParallel' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am fine-tuning `swin_base_patch4_window7_224` model based on pre-trained model in pytorch `timm` library by utilizing `nn.DataParallel()` for two gpus. After fine-tuning, I would like to visualize activation map through `gradcam` but unfortunately it gives an error.

**Code**

```
ptcfg = timm.models.registry.get_pretrained_cfg('swin_base_patch4_window7_224')
ptcfg['file'] = 'model_swin.pth'
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(timm.models.swin_base_patch4_window7_224(pretrained=True, pretrained_cfg=ptcfg, drop_path_rate=0.2), device_ids=[0,1])
model.eval()
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/pytorch-image-classification/xai.py", line 88, in <module>
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(timm.models.swin_base_patch4_window7_224(pretrained=True, pretrained_cfg=ptcfg, drop_path_rate=0.2), device_ids=[0,1])
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/swin_transformer.py", line 597, in swin_base_patch4_window7_224
    return _create_swin_transformer('swin_base_patch4_window7_224', pretrained=pretrained, **model_kwargs)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/swin_transformer.py", line 574, in _create_swin_transformer
    model = build_model_with_cfg(
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/helpers.py", line 551, in build_model_with_cfg
    load_pretrained(
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/helpers.py", line 245, in load_pretrained
    state_dict = load_state_dict(pretrained_loc)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/helpers.py", line 58, in load_state_dict
    state_dict = clean_state_dict(checkpoint[state_dict_key] if state_dict_key else checkpoint)
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/timm/models/helpers.py", line 39, in clean_state_dict
    for k, v in state_dict.items():
  File "/home2/coremax/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1614, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'DataParallel' object has no attribute 'items'
```